# Framework Migration to Playwright

Tags: javascript, converters, playwright, webdriver-io, testautomationfx

I am trying to convert webdriverIO scripts to playwright scripts. Both are in JavaScript. I’d like to know if anyone of you have converted this type of project and is there any converter projects you encountered?

I already started manually translating to playwright. I’m looking for a quick way if possible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and yes.

No - Atleast I am not aware of anything like which automatically converts it for you.

Yes - you can `reuse` lot of code with right strategy.

Who am I? - I am someone who have migrated an large (5000+ tests) framework from Protractor to playwright successfully recently.

Here are my lessons learnt:

##### Language:

This is the most important thing. As long as new and old framework implemented in JavaScript or TypeScript , we are basically overall in the same ecosystem.

##### NodeJS:

As long as new and old framework are living in nodejs ecosystem, all the external node modules used can be re-used mostly as is.

##### Test Scripts:

As long  you are using any standard test framework( Mocha/Jasmine/Jest) for your tests scripting you can almost use it `as is` - no change if you are only calling page object methods in scripts so your actual code is hidden & encapsulated in your page objects as it should be.

##### Objects Locators( Css/Xpath):

No matter which framework/ library/ language/ tool you use they will be same and can be used as is as they are independent.

##### Page Object Methods:

This is the place where most changes may happen and even that can be avoided up to an extent if you have implemented custom wrapper functions over library functions to hide the implementation details.

##### Utility/Supporter functions

Again this depends upon how elegantly and cleanly code has been abstracted out in multiple layers to minimize the change in lowest layers only without touching any higher layers.

##### Test Data:

Again with right strategy it can also be kept totally isolated from the framework in the form of Json/xml/csv/text data and can be fed in test scripts as needed. As long it is implemented correctly, most of it can be re- used as is.

##### Configuration:

It's not a biggie as it's one time and not much code to change.

The key take away from this is - design your framework with [modular](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_design#In_machines_and_architecture) approach from beginning and [abstract](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) it out in multiple layers  in such a way that each component/ class is only [loosely coupled](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) with each other so that any piece can be replaced/ updated easily without `affecting` the whole system.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Visahl, thank you for this explanation. As I progressed, I got the same feeling about the conversion. It seems similar to what you explained.

Comment: I can't upvote at the moment. Once I reach the level, I will definitely do that.

Answer (score 0):

You must do this manually because WDIO (Selenium) has a different code style. Only Puppeteer is more-less looks the same.

Check https://playwright.dev/docs/protractor, since it's more close wdio.

Comment: I also had a similar understanding. I couldn't find a reliable solution and had to rewrite it. Thanks for the answer though.